# PHP SESSION variable breaks

Tags: php, session, amazon-web-services

I have a PHP website that runs on AWS and on a local WAMP host. If I use a browser (lets say Chrome) to log into the AWS application and then open a new tab to log into the local application, the SESSION variable breaks on the AWS server. And I literally mean break, the error I get is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::refreshState()
```

The SESSION has a field ("helper") that contains an object. If I print the Session out after the critical error then it still has the "helper" object, but it only has the first 4 fields from the class definition, the rest are gone. The above mentioned error happens because the refreshState method just disappeared along with the rest of the class methods and fields

For reference, this is the first part of the helper class:

```
class SessionHelper
{
    const VIEW_TYPE_LANDING = "landing";
    const VIEW_TYPE_USER = "user";
    const VIEW_TYPE_ADMIN = "admin";


    public $logged_in_user_id;
    public $logged_in_org_user_id;
    public $login_date;
    public $prev_login_date;
    public $current_org_id;
...
```

Printing the instance out after it breaks yields:

The session stays broken in the browser even after restarting the browser. The only way to fix the error is to clear the browsing history on the browser, after which the error is gone. Any ideas what could be causing this? Any information regarding SESSIONS that break in this fashion would be welcome

[image]

Comment: Is the src file of that class included on the moment you start your session? When storing an object to a session, before unserializing the session (within session_start) the actual src file MUST be included.

Comment: Is the class definition of `SessionHelper` available on the next calls? Otherwise the `helper` object will [become useless](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.serialization.php).

Comment: Yes, I have 
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/config.php");
session_start();

before I check the SESSION variable. config.php has all the needed the includes. The application works 100%, it is only in this case that I see the behavior